# Fastlane on iOS (Swift 3, and XCode 8.2)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, fastlane

I am following a Ray Wenderlich tutorial on how to use Fastlane to build applications. (https://www.raywenderlich.com/136168/fastlane-tutorial-getting-started-2)

After the "fastlane init" command, the fastlane folder is getting created, but it only contains Appfile and Fastfile. It's missing the metadata folder, the Deliverfile and the screenshots folder.

I don't know how I should proceed. Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the metadata folder should be created with

```
fastlane supply init
```